# What is the point of using deny users="*" in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I know the meaning of

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

**deny user ?** means not give access to any user who is not authenticated but what is the meaning of **deny user ***

I come to know the meaning for **deny user *** that it means nobody will be able to access any page after or before login if **deny user *** is used.

So my question is:

If no body will be able to access any specific page when **deny user *** is used then what is the point for using it?

I am looking for guidance.

If possible, explain to me with sample situation when people have used **deny user ***.

Comment: The users can access the login page and authenticate by there.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use it to deny access to all users that aren't in a specified role:

```
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t(v=vs.71).aspx):

> At run time, the authorization module iterates through the "allow" and "deny" elements, until it finds the first one that fits a particular user.   It then grants or denies access to a URL resource depending on whether the first access rule found is an `<allow>` or a `<deny>` rule.

Comment: You can also add that while using <deny users="*"/> will disable direct access from web however the application can read and write to this directory programatically. This might be useful to keep a sensitive data secure.

Comment: @smirnov, true, though in this situation I'd prefer to use a subdirectory of App_Data which will never be visible.